# Parsing a string in quotes after a certain string

Tags: php, parsing

I'm having difficulties parsing a string. This is the structure I have:

```
"Title":"Avatar","Year":"2009","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"18 Dec 2009","Runtime":"2 h 42 min"
```

What I want to do is putting every result in an own variable so that I get $title, $year, $runtime and so on in the end.

I know, there're a lot of different PHP functions for that but after trying numerous of them and not getting the result I wanted, I just need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after few modification to your string, you can make it JSON string, by adding trailing `{` and `}`. And call [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function on modificated string:

```
$str = '"Title":"Avatar","Year":"2009","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"18 Dec 2009","Runtime":"2 h 42 min"';
$arr = json_decode("{{$str}}", true);  // True to make it array, not object

// $arr contains parsed data
```

It works, just look at [this demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JIPxyL). You can use variables like:

```
echo $arr["Title"];
```

But if you really need `$title` (*I don't suggest to do this*) you can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function

```
extract($arr);
```

And you can access it like:

```
echo $title;
```

Comment: +1, because it looks much better than `explode()` and I am glad to see more young Polish here. :) Nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
<?php
    $string = "Title":"Avatar","Year":"2009","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"18 Dec 2009","Runtime":"2 h 42 min"
    $segments = explode(',', $string);
    foreach($segments as $segment) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(':', $segment);
        echo $key, ' ', $value;
    }
```

Comment: `explode` is bad solution here. Your code will break at `"Title:":"foo"`.

Comment: @Donut i didn't see any "Title:":... only "Title":... that's why i use explode. I asume that the semi colon won't be used in the key or value. That's the risk when you don't have enough info on the source of the data

Comment: You should note it in your answer. Also, if you post anwers, post good beacue OP don't know that and may come back again that it does not work.